# How do we keep our typescript types sync between frontend and backend (React and node)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I a using React as my frontend and Nodejs as my backend. Many cases I find myself writing the same typescript definition for my server side response and frontend. Is there a way to share the typescript definition between the server and client

```
interface DadJokes {
  id:string;
  joke: string;
}
```

When you have big project and you change something on the server side types, sometimes it creates issues when you forget to change it on the client or you make a typo

Comment: Well... why not just make a file with all the types and share that file between frontend/backend? Sometimes I even have a shared *folder* that contains these types, constants (like port numbers), and environment-agnostic utilities.

Comment: I tried but the complier complain about using resource outside the project folder

Comment: [Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) is one way built into TypeScript to use a shared folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using TypeScript's `tsc` compiler you can generate declarations files for your shared types, which can then be included in both your frontend and backend projects. This can be a good option if you want to keep your shared types in a separate package or library.
2. Using git submodules you can include a git repository as a subdirectory of another repository.
3. Using [bit.dev](https://bit.dev/blog/sharing-types-between-your-frontend-and-backend-applications-l5qih48g/) you can share code components, including TypeScript types.